# If an organism is supported only by cartilage, does it have an endoskeleton?

Tags: ichthyology, vertebrates

Lamprey and sharks lack bones, but does this mean they are not classified as having an endoskelton? Does an organism need bone to be considered as having an endoskeleton?

Comment: *"Sharks have an internal skeleton made of cartilage .."* - http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/triple_ocr_gateway/the_living_body/skeletons/revision/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoskeleton)

> An endoskeleton (From Greek ἔνδον, éndon = "within", "inner" + σκελετός, skeletos = "skeleton") is an internal support structure of an animal, composed of mineralized tissue.

[Cartilage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartilage) is a mineralized tissue so it counts as a skeleton from this definition. A bit further in the wikipedia article it says

> The vertebrate endoskeleton is basically made up of two types of tissues (bone and cartilage)